# Zend Lucene search relevancy

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

What are the best practices to configure Zend Lucene to make the search results more relevant?

i have the following fields and document type

```
 productname (Text)
 description (Text)
 category (Keyword)
```

Please give some sample codes.

Comment: Please specify what you mean with "more relevant". Does lucene do not return the documents you expected?

Comment: yes the result looks very irrelevant. there are more relevant products than the returned results

Answer (score 2):

There are two concepts that come to my mind with your question, yet not sure exactly what you're looking for.

**Score**: A rating that indicates to what extent a document matches the search query. From the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.searching.html#zend.search.lucene.searching.results-scoring):

> Zend_Search_Lucene uses the same
>   scoring algorithms as Java Lucene. All
>   hits in the search result are ordered
>   by score by default.

```
$hits = $index->find($query);
foreach ($hits as $hit) {
    echo $hit->id;
    echo $hit->score;
}
```

The score is by default retrieved and applied to order the results from more to less relevant, thus it must be assumed that you need something else.

**Term Boosting**: Used to influence the relevance of individual terms within a query. Quoting once more the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.query-language.html#zend.search.lucene.query-language.boosting):

> Boosting allows you to control the
>   relevance of a document by boosting
>   individual terms. For example, if you
>   are searching for

```
PHP framework
```

> and you want the term "PHP" to be more
>   relevant boost it using the ^ symbol
>   along with the boost factor next to
>   the term. You would type:

```
PHP^4 framework
```

> This will make documents with the term
>   PHP appear more relevant. You can also
>   boost phrase terms and subqueries as
>   in the example:

```
"PHP framework"^4 "Zend Framework"
```

Does this help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Getting relevant result from any search engine is hard work.
With the level of detail you specify, it is hard to give you any specific advice.
I suggest you start with [this paper](http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Debugging-Relevance-Issues-Search).